# How to (is it possible to) fix Mac drive on Linux?

Tags: partition, macos, fsck, hfs+

I have an external USB 4 TB hard drive formatted into Mac OS, which has stopped to be determined in Mac OS. It has 2 partitions, one of which is seen under Windows Disk Management tool, which is probably precreated at the factory.

Under linux `lsblk` shows it as

```
$lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdd      8:48   0   3,7T  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   128M  0 part
└─sdd2   8:50   0   3,7T  0 part
```

`fdisk` shows

```
$sudo fdisk -l

...

Disk /dev/sdd: 3,7 TiB, 4000787027968 bytes, 7814037164 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3162E29F-0091-414C-9642-AB784F285608

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd2  264192 7814037127 7813772936  3,7T unknown

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Attempt to `mount` shows:

```
# sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdd2 /media/myhfsdrive
mount: /media/myhfsdrive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd2, missing codepage or helper program, or other e
rror.
```

with `dmesg` saying

```
[  356.907713] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

attempt to fix partition says

```
$ sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdd2
** /dev/sdd2
```

and exits.

I can `dd` entire disk or partiton.

What could happen with this drive and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you know its a hfs+ filesystem ? (and not APFS or whatever else I mean) ?

Comment: This is for apple.stackexchange.com or superuser.com You could give R-Studio Undelete a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 - it's the best file recovery application I've ever dealt with. It looks like your partition is heavily damaged. Mind that reading from it may actually lead to a catastrophic failure if it's physically failing. Please work with the DD image instead.

Comment: @MC68020 I don't. How to know?

Answer (score 2):

Either the filesystem is actually of hfs+ type and is more or less badly broken or the filesystem is not of hfs+ type.

---

Since `mount` claimed it is not of hfs+ type (deduced from the reading of the *magic number*) only your own knowledge can state mount is actually wrong. (The *magic number* is actually corrupted)
There are some (non automatic) ways to fix that under Linux.
However, you can easily understand that… if this assumption (fs type = hfs+) is incorrect… fiddlings will necessarily be tedious and harmful.

---

If your disk is a SSD and the filesystem was created post 2018, the probability is high that mount is correct because the filesystem is actually of [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) type. (*1)
AFAIK, Linux native support for APFS is (todate) left to [proprietary drivers](https://dl.paragon-software.com/doc/APFS_user_manual.pdf) and [self-claimed experimental *fsprogs](https://github.com/linux-apfs/apfsprogs).

---

Whatever the case, the advice given by Artem in OP's comment is wise : Work on the dd image.

---

1 : Finding the *magic* word "NXSB" in the first few bytes (at offset 0x20) of some partition dump would be a valid indication.

[image]